# How do I troubleshoot responses with WP HTTP API?

Tags: http

I make a GET call to API, call is supposed to return no data:

- browser (and sniffer) give me 200-OK response with `null` text as body;
- `wp_remote_get()` gives me 200-OK response with string of **binary garbage** as body.

Other API requests (that are supposed to and do return non-empty data) work perfectly fine.

Where to start poking HTTP API to figure out why it ends up with garbage?

Here is dump of full response data:

```
array
  'headers' => 
    array
      'date' => string 'Tue, 22 Feb 2011 16:51:03 GMT' (length=29)
      'server' => string 'Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)' (length=22)
      'x-powered-by' => string 'PHP/5.2.16' (length=10)
      'content-encoding' => string 'deflate' (length=7)
      'vary' => string 'Accept-Encoding' (length=15)
      'content-length' => string '17' (length=2)
      'connection' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'content-type' => string 'application/json; charset=utf-8' (length=31)
  'body' => string 'x��+��������_' (length=17)
  'response' => 
    array
      'code' => int 200
      'message' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  'cookies' => 
    array
      empty
```

Comment: Doesn't the wp http api returns a WP_Error on failure?

Comment: It does. But in this case it's not failure - it's valid (I think) response, whose body gets garbled by WP for some reason.

Comment: It might help if we knew what you were `GET`ing so we could reproduce ...

Comment: @EAMann private API key so can't post it.

Comment: In that case, I'd try just walking through the `wp_remote_get()` routine and checking what data it's got.  I don't see anywhere in the code where it generates extra cruft like you're seeing ... and without the ability to test it myself, that's the best I can give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[update]** Support for compression method, used by MailChimp, [had been implemented in WP core in version 3.3](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18273).

---

This issue [came up again](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/argh-have-done-all-setup-but-cant-get-plugin-to-work) and this time I was able to reproduce and troubleshoot it.

WordPress declares that is expects deflated data with high priority, but for some reason it cannot inflate some responses - they are not recognized by either `gzinflate()` or `WP_Http_Encoding::compatible_gzinflate()`.

In my specific case there seems to have been two extra bytes at start that caused this. Figured out from [comments to `gzinflate()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php) that are also source of `WP_Http_Encoding::compatible_gzinflate()`, but apparently that function is not perfect.

Crude quick fix that checks if response holds JSON data and tries to correct compression issue otherwise:

```
add_filter('http_response', 'mailchimp_http_response_inflate_fix', 10, 3);

function mailchimp_http_response_inflate_fix($response, $args, $url) {

    if( false === strpos($url, 'sts.mailchimp.com') )
        return $response;

    $json = json_decode($response['body']);

    if( is_null($json) ) {

        $inflate = @gzinflate(substr($response['body'], 2));

        if( false !== $inflate )
            $response['body'] = $inflate;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We tracked it down to content-encoding' => string 'deflate' (length=7) being at fault.

WP_HTTP is adding in a deflate header for no reason and un gzip compressing the results.
It only happens when the body of the response is under a certain string length.

Very annoying when all you want isa 1 or a 0.

A query to WP_Hackers hasn't resulted in a fix.
Might have to chase it up further.....

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Any idea on how to reliably replicate it?