# How to control accept encoding on HTTP API requests?

Tags: http-api

Related to [this ticket about issues with inflating data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/how-do-i-troubleshoot-responses-with-wp-http-api).

So far it had been suggested by API's support to [request gzip instead of deflate](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mailchimp-api-discuss/iIhIgMECPJE/discussion).

However I cannot find a way to override WP settings that set deflate with highest priority as accepted encoding for all requests.

Related functions - `WP_Http_Encoding::is_available()` and `WP_Http_Encoding::accept_encoding()`.

Is there any hook or other option to control this that I am missing?

Comment: I removed my previous answer because it was not a positive resolution to your question (and rather an answer saying that I can find no simple answer). Additionally, upon second look of previous answer, it was too short/thin with context and examples.

Comment: I have tired to look into the question ("Is there any hook or other option to control this that I am missing?") again and see no direct means to hook or filter WordPress' WP_Http_Encoding class (where the methods is_available, accept_encoding, and decompress are found).  There are a few hooks and filters with in WP_http but none that I can see effecting deflate. Unfortunately, I can see no means to change WordPress' deflate priority outside of making edits and submitting patches to the core.  Can you provide code examples of the request made by WordPress that needs a deflate method to be set?

Comment: @Jonnybojangles see links in question for use case... This is probably quite the edge case, but lack of control over this sucks big way when you do need to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite an edge case, but the accepted encoding types should be filterable nonetheless.  I can see a few situations where fine, granular control over this header would be useful (as in adding an API that uses non-standard encoding).

So, while there's no stock hook for this, I have created a [Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20142) for it and submitted a [patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/20142/20142.diff).  If you voice support on the ticket, maybe we can raise enough noise to get it incorporated into a future release.

Comment: Thank you for raising issue there, as you know I don't do trac much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, there's no hook for that.

Long answer: You could possibly submit a patch at [WordPress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/), if you really need to adjust this option. Personally, I didn't ever had problemes with `WP_Http_Encoding::accept_encoding()` and the question you [mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/how-do-i-troubleshoot-responses-with-wp-http-api) could be answered by manually `gzinflate()` the response. IMHO, this seems to be the only solution until someone submits a patch.